# Spell checker on visualforce page

Tags: visualforce

I need spell checker for some of the text area /rich text area fields on visualforce page.
There is an idea posted on IdeaExchange.Is there any work around for this.

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BrhqAAC

Comment: Some browsers, such as Chrome and Firefox, have a native spell-check included. I don't know if/how well they work for non-English languages, though, in case that's a concern.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can enable a spell checker...along with many many more options in ckeditor using some javascript on your page.  Its the same  editor that the regular rich text editor they normally use but you'll just be adding other options including a spell check button.

simply add the following code to any visualforce page.   the only setting you need to update is where is says CKEDITOR replace('...'

us the $Component global to target your text area

{!$Component.blogForm.blogBlock.blogSection.blogBody}

this should be the selector of the textarea you want to use... full documentation on how to use the $Component global to find the selector of your text field here

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_variables_global_component.htm

it should work both with rich text area fields or even just regular text area fields

```
// The rich text field itself
<apex:inputTextArea value="{!Post__c.Body__c}" id="blogBody" richText="false" />

/*
   The rest of the form
*/

// at the bottom of the page add the script to update CK editor
<script src="/ckeditor/ckeditor-3.6.2/ckeditor.js?t=3.6.2.3" type="text/javascript"/>

// ckeditor replace with options
<script>CKEDITOR.timestamp = '3.6.2.1';
var prototocolAndHost = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host;
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace('{!$Component.blogForm.blogBlock.blogSection.blogBody}', {baseHref : prototocolAndHost + '/ckeditor/ckeditor-3.6.2/', customConfig : '/ckeditor/ckeditor-3.6.2/ckeditor.config.js', height : '425', bodyId : 'articleEdit:createDocumentForm:sectionRepeat:0:fieldRepeat:0:fieldName:textAreaDelegate_00NG0000009Thtt_rta_body', toolbar : 'Full', sharedSpaces : { top : 'cke_topSpace', bottom : ' cke_bottomSpace' }, filebrowserImageUploadUrl : '/_ui/common/request/servlet/RtaImageUploadServlet', contentsCss : ['/sCSS/27.0/sprites/1362621144000/Theme3/default/gc/ArticleHtmlDetailElem.css'], disableNativeSpellChecker : false,language : 'en-us',sfdcLabels : { CkeMediaEmbed : { title : 'Embed Multimedia Content', description : 'Use &lt;iframe&gt; code from DailyMotion, Vimeo, and Youtube.', subtitle : 'Paste &amp;lt;iframe&amp;gt; code here:', exampleTitle : 'Example:', example : '\n            \n                &lt;iframe width=\&quot;560\&quot; height=\&quot;315\&quot; src=\&quot;https://www.youtube.com/embed/KcOm0TNvKBA\&quot; frameborder=\&quot;0\&quot; allowfullscreen&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;\n            \n        ', iframeMissing : 'Invalid &lt;iframe&gt; element. Please use valid code from the approved sites.'}, sfdcSwitchToText : { sfdcSwitchToTextAlt : 'Use plain text'}, CkeImageDialog : { uploadTab : 'Upload Image', infoTab_url : 'URL', error : 'Error:', uploadTab_desc_info : 'Enter a description of the image for visually impaired users', uploadTab_desc : 'Description', infoTab_url_info : 'Example: http://www.mysite.com/myimage.jpg', btn_insert : 'Insert', missingUrlError : 'You must enter a URL', uploadTab_file : 'Select Image', infoTab_desc : 'Description', btn_upadte : 'Update', wrongFileTypeError : 'You can insert only .gif .jpeg and .png files.', infoTab : 'Web Address', title : 'Insert Image', infoTab_desc_info : 'Enter a description of the image for visually impaired users', uploadTab_file_info : 'Maximum size 1 MB. Only png, gif or jpeg'}, CkeImagePaste : { CkeImagePasteWarning : 'Pasting an image is not working properly with Firefox, please use [Copy Image location] instead.'}}});
</script>
```

this enables all the ckeditor options and looks like:

[image: CKeditor with all the options enabled]

Comment: This is great.  I failed to get this working and thats why I deleted my answer.  I found some posts suggesting this disableNativeSpellChecker only works with firefox.  Is this accurate in your experience?

Comment: hmm it seems to work fine for me in chrome as well?

Comment: This no longer appears to function as a work-around.

Comment: Works just fine for me?

Comment: It's not working for me, this is what the console is throwing:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getEditor' of undefined
a @ ckeditor.js?t=4.5.3.3:300
CKEDITOR.replace @ ckeditor.js?t=4.5.3.3:304

Answer (score 4):

One possible workaround is to take advantage of the browsers spell checking capabilities.   Firefox, Chrome, and IE10 have a spell checker that you can enable in their advanced settings.  I have used this in my VF pages and it works fine.

https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95604?hl=en

http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-do-i-use-firefox-spell-checker

http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/Browser/SpellChecking/

[image]

I know isn't a great solution as you can't control the browser settings for each individual user, but it definitely is one work around

As @sfdcfox points out, [BJSpell](https://code.google.com/p/bjspell/%20%22BJSpell) is also a possible solution to support older versions of IE.  I have never personally used BJSpell with SF though.

Comment: Users are on Internet Explorer

Comment: I was afraid of that.  While there is nothing native, there are a great number of add-ons that allow for spell checking in IE.  A quick google search gave me many possibilities

Comment: I believe [IE10](http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/Browser/SpellChecking/) has spell checking built in (just like Chrome and Firefox).

Comment: Yes, it appears as though you're right.  Thanks @Matthew Keefe

Comment: But Users are on IE8,IE9

Comment: Then I believe your best option would be an add on

Comment: You might look into [BJSpell](https://code.google.com/p/bjspell/) as one possible solution if you absolutely insist on supporting IE, but you're still facing the fact that all versions less than IE10 are inferior to almost any other browser out there.

Comment: @sfdcfox .Can you please post some example with BJSPell

Comment: I'll see if I can write up something, but that's probably moot-- IE8 and less are losing support in the next release. This means that only IE9 will be supported and won't have native spell-checking.